# Конвертация двух объектов из JsonArray

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, gson

От сервера приходит JSON:

```
{
"status":"succes",
"data":[
    {
        "id":"1",
        "title":"name",
        "value":"temp_val"
    },{
        "id":"10",
        "title":"name",
        "max":"maximum_value",
        "variable":"current_variable"
    }]
}
```

Имею структуру классов:

```
public class TableRow{
private String id;
private String title;
// constructor + getters/setters
    public static class TableValue extends TableRow{
    private String value;
    // constructor + getters/setters
    }
    public static class TableVariable extends TableRow{
    private String maximum;
    private String variable;
    // constructor + getters/setters
    }
}
```

Конвертер подключаю ко всему gson

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(ServerResponse.class, new Converter())
            .create();
....
api = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://base-url.ru")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .client(httpClient.build())//ofl
            .build()
            .create(Api.class);
```

Как объявить в `Конвертере` выходной класс, чтобы можно было получить `List<TableRow>`

```
rResponse = new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray, ???.class);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по json у вас:

```
class TableRow {
  String id;
  String title;
  String max;
  String value;
  String variable;
}

class ServerResponse {
  String status;
  List<TableRow> data;
}
```

Пример:

```
//json
String jsonOutput= "..."

//преобразование json в объект
ServerResponse serverResponse = new Gson().fromJson(jsonOutput, ServerResponse.class);

for (TableRow item: serverResponse.data){
    item.id
    item.title
    ...
}
```

Comment: Исправил входной json. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, Ваше решение подходит под такие данные?

Comment: Добавил String variable. В первом случае где id==1 variable будет не заполнено, во втором случае - заполнено. Массив должен содержать одинаковый набор данных. Но в вашем случае мы просто добавили в класс все возможные свойства, и в зависимости от json некоторые будут не заполнены (null).

Comment: Можете объяснить или направить на материал по строке  
 ```Type listType = new TypeToken<ServerResponse>(){}.getType(); ``` 
я не понимаю как ее использовать

Comment: Вы спросили "Как объявить в Конвертере выходной класс rResponse = new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray, ???.class);" - это то же самое. Давайте перепишу: `ServerResponse rResponse = new Gson().fromJson(jsonOutput, listType);`

Comment: Простите, видимо еще не проснулся, меня интересует строка ```Type listType = new TypeToken<ServerResponse>(){}.getType();```

Comment: Извините поторопился. listType нужен если у вас json - массив элементов. Например: `[{"id":"1"},{...}]`. А у вас - объект с массивом внутри. Тогда достаточно `ServerResponse serverResponse = new Gson().fromJson(jsonOutput, ServerResponse.class);` Поправил ответ.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89269/discussion-between-jorik-and-virex-84).